How to pass arguments when including other launch files in ROS2?
In ROS1, you could include other launch files and pass them args with pass_all_args=true.
How do you pass args to an included launch file in ROS2? Also, is there a way to do this with the .yaml launch files?
I tried
launch:
  # include MAVROS ardupilot launch
  - include:
      file: "$(find-pkg-share mavros)/launch/apm.launch"
      pass_all_args: true

But it said "ValueError: Unexpected key(s) found in `include`: {'pass_all_args'}"

I got it.
launch:
  # include MAVROS ardupilot launch
  - include:
      file: "$(find-pkg-share mavros)/launch/apm.launch"
      arg:
        - 
            name: "fcu_url"
            value: "udp://:14553@"
        -
            name: "respawn_mavros"
            value: "true"


close the question by accepting your own answer.
